while loop removes quotes escapes making jq fail to parse json
"$response":
[{"word":"world","phonetic":"/wɝld/","phonetics":[{"text":"/wɝld/","audio":"https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/media/pronunciations/en/world-ca.mp3","sourceUrl":"https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=238003","license":{"name":"BY-SA 3.0","url":"https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0"}},{"text":"/wɵːld/","audio":""},{"text":"/wɜːld/","audio":""},{"text":"/wɝld/","audio":"https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/media/pronunciations/en/world-us.mp3","sourceUrl":"https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=67249678","license":{"name":"BY-SA 4.0","url":"https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0"}}],"meanings":[{"partOfSpeech":"noun","definitions":[{"definition":"(with \"the\") Human collective existence; existence in general.","synonyms":[],"antonyms":[],"example":"There will always be lovers, till the world's end."},{"definition":"The Universe.","synonyms":[],"antonyms":[]},{"definition":"(with \"the\") The Earth.","synonyms":[],"antonyms":[],"example":"People are dying of starvation all over the world."},{"definition":"A planet, especially one which is inhabited or inhabitable.","synonyms":[],"antonyms":[],"example":"Our mission is to travel the galaxy and find new worlds."},{"definition":"A very large extent of country.","synonyms":[],"antonyms":[]},{"definition":"(speculation) A realm, such as planet, containing one or multiple societies of beings, especially intelligent ones.","synonyms":[],"antonyms":[],"example":"the world of Narnia; the Wizarding World of Harry Potter; a zombie world"},{"definition":"An individual or group perspective or social setting.","synonyms":[],"antonyms":[],"example":"In the world of boxing, good diet is all-important."},{"definition":"The part of an operating system distributed with the kernel, consisting of the shell and other programs.","synonyms":[],"antonyms":[]},{"definition":"A subdivision of a game, consisting of a series of stages or levels that usually share a similar environment or theme.","synonyms":[],"antonyms":[],"example":"Have you reached the boss at the end of the ice world?"},{"definition":"The twenty-second trump or major arcana card of the tarot.","synonyms":[],"antonyms":[]},{"definition":"A great amount.","synonyms":[],"antonyms":[],"example":"Taking a break from work seems to have done her a world of good."},{"definition":"Age, era","synonyms":[],"antonyms":[]}],"synonyms":["planet","circle","Earth","Sol III","globe"],"antonyms":[]},{"partOfSpeech":"verb","definitions":[{"definition":"To consider or cause to be considered from a global perspective; to consider as a global whole, rather than making or focussing on national or other distinctions; compare globalise.","synonyms":[],"antonyms":[]},{"definition":"To make real; to make worldly.","synonyms":[],"antonyms":[]}],"synonyms":[],"antonyms":[]}],"license":{"name":"CC BY-SA 3.0","url":"https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0"},"sourceUrls":["https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/world"]}]

^ notice definition":"(with \"the\" <--- quotes are escaped
echo "$response" | jq -c '.[].meanings[]' | while read meaning; do
  echo "$meaning"
  echo "$meaning" | jq -r '.'
  exit
done

^ returns:
{"partOfSpeech":"noun","definitions":[{"definition":"(with "the") Human collective existence; existence in general.","synonyms":[],"antonyms":[],"example":"There will always be lovers, till the world's end."},{"definition":"The Universe.","synonyms":[],"antonyms":[]},{"definition":"(with "the") The Earth.","synonyms":[],"antonyms":[],"example":"People are dying of starvation all over the world."},{"definition":"A planet, especially one which is inhabited or inhabitable.","synonyms":[],"antonyms":[],"example":"Our mission is to travel the galaxy and find new worlds."},{"definition":"A very large extent of country.","synonyms":[],"antonyms":[]},{"definition":"(speculation) A realm, such as planet, containing one or multiple societies of beings, especially intelligent ones.","synonyms":[],"antonyms":[],"example":"the world of Narnia; the Wizarding World of Harry Potter; a zombie world"},{"definition":"An individual or group perspective or social setting.","synonyms":[],"antonyms":[],"example":"In the world of boxing, good diet is all-important."},{"definition":"The part of an operating system distributed with the kernel, consisting of the shell and other programs.","synonyms":[],"antonyms":[]},{"definition":"A subdivision of a game, consisting of a series of stages or levels that usually share a similar environment or theme.","synonyms":[],"antonyms":[],"example":"Have you reached the boss at the end of the ice world?"},{"definition":"The twenty-second trump or major arcana card of the tarot.","synonyms":[],"antonyms":[]},{"definition":"A great amount.","synonyms":[],"antonyms":[],"example":"Taking a break from work seems to have done her a world of good."},{"definition":"Age, era","synonyms":[],"antonyms":[]}],"synonyms":["planet","circle","Earth","Sol III","globe"],"antonyms":[]}
jq: parse error: Invalid literal at line 1, column 64

quotes escapes are gone and jq fails to parse.
I have tried adding flags to echo (-n and -e) but that didn't help.

Just adding -r isn't sufficient to entirely prevent read from modifying content on the way in, by the way -- make it while IFS= read -r meaning to avoid also trimming leading and trailing whitespace. See BashFAQ #1 for extensive coverage of relevant best practices.

(...also, if you want to set any variables inside your while read loop that persist after the loop exits, or if you expected exit to exit the script as a whole and not just the loop, be aware of BashFAQ #24; in general, while IFS= read -r meaning; do ...; done < <(jq -c '.[].meanings[]' <<<"$response") is more robust code)

...mind, if you really do mean to only read the first meaning and not loop through any others (as the exit implies), you could just write IFS= read -r meaning < <(jq -c '.[].meanings[]' <<<"$response") and not use any while loop at all.

(btw, to understand why none of my examples above use  echo at all, see the excellent answer on [unix.se] to Why is printf better than echo? by Stephane Chazelas, describing in detail why echo's behavior is unreliable and surprising).

Thank you for providing so much information, I will be reading it now!


notice definition":"(with \"the\" <--- quotes are escaped

Use read -r:
while read -r meaning; do …

See man bash on read:
-r     Backslash does not act as an escape character.  The backslash
       is considered to be part of the line.  In particular, a
       backslash-newline pair may not then be used as a line
       continuation.


Thank you! I wasted couple hours on this...

@sloppy FYI, shellcheck says "SC2162 (info): read without -r will mangle backslashes."
